# Why do I have two completions when editing python file?

Tags: python, completion, elpy

[image]

As in the picture, when I editing python file, there are two completions. Why is that? Thank you very much.

Following are my init.el related to elpy and completion:

```
(elpy-enable)
;;(setq elpy-rpc-backend "jedi")
;;(autoload 'jedi:setup "jedi" nil t)
;;(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
;;(setq jedi:complete-on-dot t)                 ; optional
(elpy-use-ipython)
(global-eldoc-mode -1)

(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
;;(defun my/python-mode-hook ()
 ;; (add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-jedi))
;;(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'my/python-mode-hook)
```

Comment: Try to disable `auto-complete-mode`, that should remove the first/upper auto-complete selection.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing two popups because you've enabled two different auto-completion systems at the same time.  Elpy activates company-mode, jedi.el activates auto-complete-mode.  I'd suggest removing jedi.el from your config as Elpy handles that part already.

Comment: So I delete jedi, but it is still the same. I don't think it is related to jedi, since in my init.el, I comment all things related to jedi.